# Orientable double-cover of the Mobius strip

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, cobordism

Let C<sub>0</sub> be the cylinder, M<sub>1</sub> the Mobius band (a cylinder with 1 twist), and C<sub>2</sub> a cylinder with 2 twists (each embedded in R<sup>3</sup>).

Although C<sub>0</sub> and C<sub>2</sub> are diffeomorphic, intuitively one should think that C<sub>2</sub> is a better choice for the oriented double-cover of M<sub>1</sub>, as it should preserve the notion of the "twisting" of M<sub>1</sub>.  Clearly C<sub>0</sub> is diffeomorphic to C<sub>2</sub>, but the two are not ambient isotopic within R<sup>3</sup>.

How specifically can we state "C<sub>2</sub> is the better choice for the oriented double-cover of M<sub>1</sub>, as opposed to C<sub>0</sub>"?  Is there an intrinsic way of doing so? Is there some way to phrase this in terms of cobordism?

Answer (score 8):

I don't know whether there's a way to phrase it in terms of (co)bordism, but you might observe that the standard embedding of $C_1$ has a normal bundle; the tubular nhd theorem says that that bundle, too, can be embedded so that that the 0-section is exactly $C_1$. Taking the image of $[-1, 1]$ in each fiber, you get a 3-manifold with boundary; if you take the boundary in the fiber direction, you get an embedding of the double cover. Here's a picture, before and after taking the double-cover (crudely drawn, but it's the best I can do at 5 AM):

Before: [image]

After:[image]

Now you can take that second surface, and claim (or try to claim) that it's ambient isotopic to the twice-twisted cylinder, but not to the untwisted cylinder. Experimenting with a piece of paper confirms this. (The isotopy to the twice-twisted cylinder is easy. To prove there's no isotopy to the untwisted cylinder, look at the linking number between the top and bottom edge of the cylinder. That's invariant under isotopy, but in the untwisted case it's zero, and in the double-twist case, it's two.)

Comment: I appreciate your response, especially because it is constructive in a readily visual manner, and I think the construction provides a mapping that could prove useful. However, I still wonder how to intrinsically describe the difference between  the annulus and the twice-twisted annulus. I'm thinking that characteristic classes of vector bundles will answer this. But I ask now 1) which characteristic classes should I consider, and 2) can one find a suitable characteristic class from which to construct the appropriate cover?

Comment: Alas, no: the vector bundles that are isomorphic (as vector bundles) to the annulus and the twice-twisted annulus have exactly the same characteristic classes, so there's nothing there. The linking number between the 0-section and an everywhere non-zero section is "0" in the first and "2" in the second case, so those are distinct, but they're *extrinsic* properties: they arise from/live in 3-space, not in the annuli. But that's no surprise, since the two annuli are diffeomorphic, so they have all the same algebraic properties.

Comment: See also visualization https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Orientation_cover_of_Mobius_strip.webm