# Question about oriented double covering

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I have a question regarding when $M^*$ is the oriented doublel covering of $M$. Suppose for example $M$ is the Mobius strip. As it is non-orientable, $M^*$ should be connected. Indeed from some pictures that I saw, it is path connected. Look at the picture in this post [Orientable double-cover of the Mobius strip](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816676/orientable-double-cover-of-the-mobius-strip) by John Hughes.

(**update: be wary of the wrong definition in the next paragraph!**)

Now as a set, I denote $M^*$ by $\{(p, +_p)| p \in M\} \cup \{(p, -_p)| p \in M\}$ where here $+_p$ denotes the equivalence class of all positive orientations on $T_pM$ and $-_p$ is defined similarly. My confusion is as follows. If $\gamma:[0, 1]\rightarrow M^*$ is a curve connecting $(p, +_p)$ to $(q, -_q)$, at which point does a positive orientation (the $+$) change to a negative orientation (to a $-$)? This is very weired to me. Even when I look at the drawing of the double cover, there seems to be something weired about it. It is indeed a double cover and it is orientable. But I still can't correspond this mathematical construction to the picture I see!

**update**: The following answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2893383/148256 deals with a correct definition.

Comment: If the oriented double cover is connected, the original manifold is not orientable, and there is no global consistent way of talking about $(p,+_p)$ and $(q,+_q)$. Only local.

Comment: What is a positive orientation on $T_pM?$

Comment: I consider the space of non-zero linear $m$-forms on $T_pM$ which is one dimensional. Then I consider an arbitrary element $v$ in this space. I call $+_p:= \{tv| t > 0\}$ the positive orientation and $-_p:= \{tv| t < 0\}$ the negative orientation. You asked a good question. I'm choosing an arbitrary vector $v_p$ for each $p \in M$. That's a lot of choice being involved! This shows that there is no contradiction that I was searching for. There is however still something that confuses me which I don't know how to explain even.

Comment: @didier You're correct. There's a well defined way to consider both orientations at the same time but not a consistent global labeling of positive and negative. Would you be able to help me realize 1) What is the double covering actually doing that makes the construction orientable? 2) Why do people define it like this? Why is $M^*$ different from $(M \times \{1\}) \cup (M \times \{2\})$? 3) What's the intuition behind connectivity is equivalent to $non-orientability?

Comment: Maybe it's useful to add another "intermediate" statement in this equivalence: there is no continuous section $M \to M^*$, ie no continuous choice of $p \mapsto (\text{orientation at } p)$, iff $M$ is not orientable. It is easy to see that the image of such a section would be a proper clopen set, so one direction of the equivalence with connectivity of $M^*$ is clear.

Comment: Just another question out of curiousity. Is one able to always construct the oriented double covering in finite dimensional case using the tubular neighbourhood theorem (as was done in the post that I shared the link of)?

Comment: No, that is not always possible, because the oriented double cover is defined for manifolds in general, not just for codimension-1 submanifolds of Euclidean spaces.

Comment: I'm not convinced. Why does this rule out the statement when we are just considering the finite dimensional case?